# Executing HQL scripts using Bash Script vs Using Oozie

Tags: shell, hive, oozie, cloudera-cdh

I have a a number of hql files that I need to execute and I was wondering what the best approach to this is.

Right now we are using a bash/shell script that loops through all hql files in a path and performs "hive -f *.hql" The issue we are having with this approach is there is CPU limitation with the number of jobs that you can kick off at once.

Do you think a better approach would be to use Oozie workflow to submit the hql files instead?

Any other suggestions would help too

Answer (score 1):

You could submit a few at a time using `xargs` and `find`, for example to submit 10 files at a time

```
find path -maxdepth 1 -name '*.hql' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 10 hive -f
```

Comment: I am more curious about the oozie approach. Right now we do submit 5 jobs a time through a similar approach within my shell script

Answer (score 0):

you can use the spring frame work : use shell script to call the hql and call shell script using spring bean

```
<step id="processing">
            <tasklet transaction-manager="jobRepository-transactionManager">
                <beans:bean class="example.spring.batch.util.ShellScriptTasklet" scope="step">
                    <beans:property name="shellScript" value="${probb.home}/bin/xyz.sh" />
                    <beans:property name="seviority" value="${imr.seviority}" />
                    <beans:list value-type="java.lang.String">
                            <beans:value>${project_properties}</beans:value>
                        </beans:list>
                    </beans:property>
                </beans:bean>
            </tasklet>
            <end on="FAILED" />
            <next on="*" to="next_job_id" />
        </step>
        <step id="next_job_id">
        .....
        </step>
```